# Bucket Distribution with Weighted Average in Power BI

Tags: database, powerbi, switch-statement, dax, bucket

I am a complete newbie to Power Bi and need to complete this project
I have a data set with 77,270 rows and 78 columns

LTV bucket distribution (in count and dollars) *I have a column titled LTV

Buckets I am trying to achieve:

## 0%-60%

## 60%-70%

## 70%-80%

## 80%-90%

## Greater than 90%

Do the bucket distribution by property type (this is a column name)

Do the bucket distribution by state/geography (this is a column name)

Average LTV by count weighted and dollar weighted (I tried to do this with quick measure, but I saw no change to the data/output)

- for dollar weighted = LTV / (Cmmt Amount 1)(LTV 1) + (Cmmt Amount 2)(LTV 2) + (Cmmt Amount 3)(LTV 3)
- For count weighted = LTV / (Count 1)(LTV 1) + (Count 2)(LTV 2) + (Count 3)(LTV 3) *there is no count column

Average LTV by count weighted and dollar weight by property type (I tried to do this directly in a stacked column chart, but the average is not being represented)

Average LTV by count weighted and dollar weight by state/geography (I did this as a map, but the average is not being represented)

Sample Data:

| LTV | Property Type | State | Cmmt Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 51% | Office | IL | $2000 |
| 72% | Retail | MN | $5000 |

I tried the quick measure method, maps and a stacked column chart. When I did the quick measure nothing changed from my regular chart with cmmt amount and LTV to the averages with distribution.

I tried doing the DAX method but its very complicated and I probably messed that up too see attached:

```
LTV = 
VAR Val = Bucket[LTV]
RETURN
SWITCH(
    TRUE(),
    Val <= 60,
    "0-60 %",
    Val > 60 || Val <= 70,
    "60-70%",
    Val > 70 || Val <= 80, 
    "70-80%",
    Val > 80 || Val <= 90, 
    "80-90%",
    "90+ months"
)
```

Is it possible to achieve what I am trying to do in one visualization? I would like all of this to be in one tab that can be presented together.